# describing contents inside a table

Tags: conjunctions

I want to describe parameters which have been set experimentally to my algorithms. So, I listed out parameters in table 5 and also described important points as follows.

> Table 5 summarises the fundamental parameters used by the
>   reconstruction approach. The parameters are set by the user based on
>   his knowledge about data and landscape. **In terms of scene
>   complexities** for e.g. having closely located feature lines, scene 1
>   and 3 are bit complicated than scene 2. **This** illustrates by the
>   narrow *half-width* equal to 0.7m in Table 5. **On the other hand**,
>   scene1 consists of shorter edges than other two scenes, which leads to
>   accept short ridge-lines and step-edges roughly equal to 0.5m. **In
>   the case of remaining parameters**, they behave in a
>   similar manner, thus, equally set for every scene.

So, my question is I want to know whether this description is smoothly connected to each other? that mean, I first explain similarity of site1 and 3. then how site 1 deviate from others. finally, similarity of all sites. So, please comments whether my explanation has good connection and flow.

Your suggestions and corrections are also very welcome.

Comment: Please also note that a question like this could be easily considered as a proofreading, and thus off-topic on this site. It's better to discuss one point (each of your highlighted parts, for example) at a time. Giving us the alternatives you think possible is also helpful, and thus we can answer your questions better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my rough edit,

> In terms of scene complexities, **for example**, having closely located feature lines, **scenes** 1 and 3 are **a little more** complicated than scene 2. This **is illustrated** by the narrow half-width equal to 0.7m in Table 5. On the other hand, **scene 1** consists of shorter edges than other two scenes, which leads to **the acceptance of** short ridge-lines and step-edges **at about** 0.5m. **This is in contrast to** remaining parameters, **where** they behave in a similar manner, thus, **will be set** equally for every scene.

Here are a few notes:

- *E.g.* means *for example*, so avoid using "for e.g.". You can use either "e.g." or "for example".
- I changed *illustrates* to *is illustrated* because of the *by the narrow ...*. This indicates that you should use the passive voice rather than the active voice. (Depending on what you intend to say, *This illustrates the narrow half-width as being equal to 0.7m in Table 5.*)
- *Which leads to* should be followed by a noun (or a gerund). The change to *at about* might not be necessary. I just felt that it seemed to go together with *the acceptance of* better.
- I used *This is in contrast to* to emphasize the contrast you stated. Consequently, the latter part must be converted to a clause, thus a *where*.
- Though I changed your *set* into *will be set*, I think that it can be improved more. Perhaps, *will be preset* or *will be set equally be default*. But that would require more details about how your algorithms work, so I will leave that for you.

Comment: This is good. For the last bit, I like JMB's "and thus" better.

Answer (score 1):

Your flow seems fine to me. This answer corrects any error.

> Table 5 summarises the fundamental parameters used by the reconstruction approach. The parameters are set by the user based on **their** knowledge **of** data and landscape. In terms of scene **complexity**, for **example,** having closely located feature lines, **scenes** 1 and 3 are **a** bit **more** complicated than scene 2. This **is illustrated** by the narrow half-width equal to 0.7m in Table 5. On the other hand, **scene 1** consists of shorter edges than **the** other two scenes, which leads to **the acceptance of** short ridge-lines and step-edges roughly equal to 0.5m. **As for the** remaining parameters, they behave in a similar manner, **and** thus, **are** equally set for every scene.

Comment: thanks for the improvement. in 2ns sentence, .... by the USER based in HIS (OR THEIR)....  I think, user is singular.... any comments please. thanks

Comment: User is indeed singular, but saying "their" allows us to be general (and is fine as a singular form), and not specify male or female. It also helps us avoid writing "his/her" each time. (Please also see the other answer, as it contains some nice explanations which you might find useful).